# BrowserField and lost connection

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

I have an app that uses a browserfield to connect to a web-page.
All is working ok and the simulator shows the right page.

If I set the simulator Network Properties to "Out of Coverage" and click on a link in my web-page then I get an exception - in the BrowserFieldConnectionManagerImpl

How can catch this exception so I can take appropriate action?

The app is using BlackBerry SDK

The code is here:

public final class example_Screen extends MainScreen {

```
// Create the ErrorHandler class
public class MyBrowserFieldErrorHandler extends BrowserFieldErrorHandler {
    protected MyBrowserFieldErrorHandler(BrowserField browserField){
        super(browserField);
    }

    public void displayContentError(String url, String errorMessage) {
        System.out.println("JERRY: displayContentError" + url);
        System.out.println("JERRY: displayContentError" + errorMessage);
    }

    public void displayContentError(String url, InputConnection connection, Throwable t) {
        displayContentError(url, t.getMessage());
    }

    public void navigationRequestError(BrowserFieldRequest request, Throwable t) {
        displayContentError(request.getURL(), t.getMessage());
    }

    public void requestContentError(BrowserFieldRequest request, Throwable t) {
        displayContentError(request.getURL(), t.getMessage());
    }

    public InputConnection resourceRequestError(BrowserFieldRequest request, Throwable t) {
        displayContentError(request.getURL(), t.getMessage());
        InputConnection connection = null;
        return connection;
    }   

}


/**
 * Creates a new example_Screen object
 */
public example_Screen() {

    GIFEncodedImage ourAnimation = (GIFEncodedImage) GIFEncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("2.gif");       

    AnimatedGIFField _ourAnimation = new AnimatedGIFField(ourAnimation, Field.FIELD_HCENTER + Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
    this.add(_ourAnimation);
    LabelField _ourLabelField = new LabelField("Updating ...", Field.FIELD_HCENTER + Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
    this.add(_ourLabelField);                   

    int anim_ht = _ourAnimation.getPreferredHeight();
    int label_ht = _ourLabelField.getPreferredHeight();

    EncodedImage ei = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/menu.png");       

    int currentWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(ei.getWidth());
    int currentHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(ei.getHeight());

    int displayWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(Display.getWidth());
    int displayHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP((Display.getHeight() - anim_ht - label_ht));

    int scaleXFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentWidthFixed32, displayWidthFixed32);
    int scaleYFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentHeightFixed32, displayHeightFixed32);

    ei = ei.scaleImage32(scaleXFixed32, scaleYFixed32);

    BitmapField bmp = new BitmapField(ei.getBitmap(), Field.FIELD_HCENTER + Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
    add(bmp);      

    BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
    myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);       
    BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);
    add(browserField);

    browserField.requestContent("http://www.bbc.co.uk");

    BrowserFieldListener listener = new BrowserFieldListener() {
        public void documentAborted(BrowserField browserField, Document document) {
            System.out.println("JERRY: documentAborted");
        }

        public void documentCreated(BrowserField browserField, ScriptEngine scriptEngine, Document document) {
            System.out.println("JERRY: documentCreated");
        }

        public void documentError(BrowserField browserField, Document document) {
            System.out.println("JERRY: documentError");
        }

        public void documentLoaded(BrowserField browserField, Document document) {
            System.out.println("JERRY: documentLoaded");  

            Node node = document.getFirstChild();
            String nodeText = node.getTextContent();            
            int index = -1;
            if (nodeText != null) {             
                String errorText = "Error requesting content for:";                 
                index = nodeText.indexOf(errorText); 
            }

            Screen screen = browserField.getScreen();   
            try {
                synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
                    if (index == -1) {
                        System.out.println("JERRY: documentLoaded: no error");
                        int count = screen.getFieldCount();
                        if (count > 1) {
                            screen.deleteRange(0, (count-1));  
                            System.out.println("JERRY: documentLoaded: " + (count-1) + " fields deleted");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("JERRY: documentLoaded: only 1 field so none deleted");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("JERRY: documentLoaded: error");
                    }
                }
            } catch (final Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("example_Screen: documentLoaded: exception caught: " + ex.toString());
            }               

        }

        public void documentUnloading(BrowserField browserField, Document document) {
            System.out.println("JERRY: documentUnloading");
        }

        public void downloadProgress(BrowserField browserField, ContentReadEvent event) {
            System.out.println("JERRY: downloadProgress");
        }

    };
    browserField.addListener(listener);

    // Attach the Error Handler to the BrowserField
    BrowserFieldErrorHandler eHandler = new MyBrowserFieldErrorHandler(browserField);
    browserField.getConfig().setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ERROR_HANDLER, eHandler);

}
```

}

Comment: Are you talking about WebWorks/PhoneGap application or Java-based app? Please note that in your question.

Comment: I edited the question - its Java-based app

Answer (score 2):

`BrowserField` contains a method, [addListener()](http://tinyurl.com/9a3wafa) which takes a reference to [BrowserFieldListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserFieldListener.html) implementation.

Extend `BrowserFieldListener` and process errors in methods `documentError()` and `documentAborted()` of this implementation.

Then add a reference of your class instance that extends `BrowserFieldListener` to your browser field via `browserField.addListener(browserFieldListener);`.

**EDIT:**

If this does not work, then use [BrowserFieldErrorHandler](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserFieldErrorHandler.html) class from RIM API. Build your own error handler and pass its instance to the browserfield configuration.

Below, there's sample code:

```
// Create the ErrorHandler class
public class MyBrowserFieldErrorHandler extends BrowserFieldErrorHandler {
  public void displayContentError(String url, String errorMessage) {
    String error = "Error: (url=" + url + "): " + t.getMessage();
    Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_OK, error);
    logMessage(“BrowserFieldError: “ + error );
  }

 public void displayContentError(String url, InputConnection connection, Throwable t) { 
    displayContentError(url, t.getMessage());
 }

 public void requestContentError(BrowserFieldRequest request, Throwable t){
  displayContentError(request.getURL(), t.getMessage());
 }
}

// Attach the Error Handler to the BrowserField
BrowserFieldErrorHandler eHandler = new MyBrowserFieldErrorHandler();
browserField.getConfig().setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ERROR_HANDLER,eHandler);
```

I get this sample code from DevCon2010 presentation of BrowserField capabilities. You can get it here: http://dev.tuyennguyen.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/DEV49.pdf

Comment: Hi Rafael,Thanks for your answer .... but I did already try that. The documentError and documentAborted callbacks are not called. I just get an exception. I am testing using an 8900 simulator.

Comment: Hi Rafael, Thanks for the hints about BrowserFieldErrorHandler. Unfortunately this still does not work. I've edited my question to add my code (I probably made an error in my implementation!).

Comment: Try to make a very simple project with one browser field and one error handler added via browser field config. Use `System.out.println()` to log events when a particular method is called.